# SslStream.AuthenticateAsServer() blocks indefinitely

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, smtp

I am trying to create an SMTPS server (for educational purposes, mostly) but I can't seem to authenticate the server using TLS.

I got a certificate by using [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/#debianjessie-other) for Debian 8 (Jessie). I then combined the certificate and the private key into a .pfx file with `$ openssl pkcs12 -export -out fullcert.pfx -inkey privkey.pem -in cert.pem -certfile chain.pem` and I load it using `var cert = new X509Certificate2("fullcert.pfx", "password");`

The certificate I got seems to be valid, as `cert.ToString(true)` seems to show the properties of the certificate correctly and the following code correctly encrypts/decrypts a string

```
var str = "BeepBoop";
Console.WriteLine("Encrypting... ({0})", str);
var enc = pubkey.Encrypt(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str), RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
Console.WriteLine("Decrypting...");
var dec = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(privkey.Decrypt(enc, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1));
Console.WriteLine("Finished ({0})", dec);
```

<sub>Sorry for the messy code</sub>

I then pass the certificate object to another object, which uses it in the following code:

```
// PS: the server listens on port 25000
private void HandleClient(TcpClient client)
{
    Console.WriteLine("[==] BeepBoop: connection on " + port);
    //client.ReceiveTimeout = client.SendTimeout = timeout;
    Stream stream = client.GetStream();
    if(Certificate != null)
    {
        var sslStream = new SslStream(stream, false);
        Console.WriteLine("Authenticating...");
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(Certificate, false, SslProtocols.Tls, true);
        Console.WriteLine("Authenticated");
        stream = sslStream;
    }
    Write(stream, ServiceReadyReply);

    // Implementation of SMTP, which does work correctly
}
```

When I try to connect using [this SMTP tool](https://www.smtper.net/) or even Chrome (by connecting to https://localhost:25000) the program blocks indefinitely on `sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(...)` until the client times out, at which point an `AggregateException` containing an `IOException` is thrown. I have tried changing the parameters, but no combination seems to work.

This is the stacktrace I get:

```
  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x00027] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/MobileAuthenticatedStream.cs:606 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream:ProcessHandshake (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus)
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncHandshakeRequest.Run (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/AsyncProtocolRequest.cs:282 
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest+<ProcessOperation>d__24.MoveNext () [0x000ff] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/AsyncProtocolRequest.cs:221 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:447 
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest+<StartOperation>d__23.MoveNext () [0x00046] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/AsyncProtocolRequest.cs:187 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.CheckThrow (System.Boolean authSuccessCheck, System.Boolean shutdownCheck) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/MobileAuthenticatedStream.cs:91 
  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.get_SslProtocol () [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/MobileAuthenticatedStream.cs:707 
  at System.Net.Security.SslStream.get_SslProtocol () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Security/SslStream.cs:252
```

<sub>PS: I copied the certificate to my MacBook, but the exact same issue happens on my Raspberry Pi</sub>

The attribute `stream.DataAvailable` is false at the moment the exception is thrown. <sub>I don't know if this information does really matter, but I guess it is better to give too much information than too little :)</sub>

I have done quite a bit of research to my specific issue, and I found the following results which seem related to my issue:

- [C# SslStream.AuthenticateAsServer() intermittently blocks indefinitely. Recovers after restart of application.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e1892872-dec5-42a4-98cd-a7f9f02e18d7/c-sslstreamauthenticateasserver-intermittently-blocks-indefinitely-recovers-after-restart-of?forum=wcf)
- [AuthenticateAsServer blocks forever on any Jabber client but GAIM](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Windows/en-US/ca7ab119-b9b8-409d-b558-2d1293e2ad55/authenticateasserver-blocks-forever-on-any-jabber-client-but-gaim?forum=netfxnetcom)
- [Bug 976638 - System.Net.Security.SslStream hangs in AuthenticateAsServer](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=976638) (this one seems to be very similar to my issue!)
- [AuthenticateAsServer blocks forever on any Jabber client but GAIM](http://www.databaseforum.info/25/726440.aspx) (also very relevant)
- [SslStream.AuthenticateAsServer and AuthenticateAsClient intermittently block indefinitely.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0c737a04-19df-4872-8bce-15720f0556e5/sslstreamauthenticateasserver-and-authenticateasclient-intermittently-block-indefinitely?forum=wsk)
- [SslStream.AuthenticateAsServer hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43096996/sslstream-authenticateasserver-hangs)

At this point, I don't have any clue what could be going wrong. Any help is very much appreciated. If you need more information, I'll be glad to provide it.

---

**UPDATE:** When I try to connect with Chrome to my server I get `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` and an `AuthenticationException` that has an `TlsException` with `` TlsException.Message = "Unknown Secure Transport error `IllegalParam'." `` (maybe I forgot to append 'https://' to the domain name when debugging initially? I would swear I did do that then though...)

---

**UPDATE 2:** The error message is different for the MacBook and the Raspberry Pi: the above error message is from the MacBook and the following is what I get on the RPi: `Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Ssl error:1000009c:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:HTTP_REQUEST`

---

**UPDATE 3:** Good news! I got something that works (halleluja)!
I have generated a certificate for localhost using this command:

```
openssl req -x509 -out localhost.crt -keyout localhost.key \
  -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 \
  -subj '/CN=localhost' -extensions EXT -config <( \
   printf "[dn]\nCN=localhost\n[req]\ndistinguished_name = dn\n[EXT]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:localhost\nkeyUsage=digitalSignature\nextendedKeyUsage=serverAuth")
```

I got two files: `localhost.crt` and `localhost.key`. I combined these files with

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in localhost.crt -inkey localhost.key -out localhost.pfx
```

I simply pressed enter twice to generate no password for the certificate.
I then loaded the certificate with this code:

```
certificate = new X509Certificate2("/path/to/localhost.pfx");
```

and used with

```
var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n<h1>Hello world! ( ^-^)/</h1>");
var server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8443);
server.Start();
while (true)
{
    var client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
    var stream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false);
    stream.AuthenticateAsServer(certificate);
    stream.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
    Thread.Sleep(1000); // Lazy, dirty way to make sure data arrives.
    stream.Close();
}
```

I then connected to https://localhost:8443 and got the classic old message that my connection is "not secure". I continued either way and the page loaded! Hooray!

Now I only have to figure out what is going wrong with the other certificate...

---

**UPDATE 4:** Guess what... It works with my other certificate. I'm not sure what went wrong at first, but maybe there is a subtle difference between the two commands I used? The first one I used is

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out fullcert.pfx -inkey privkey.pem -in cert.pem -certfile chain.pem
```

and the one I used for my server is

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in fullchain.pem -inkey privkey.pem -out certificate.pfx
```

I then loaded the certificate like described in update 3 and it just works. The main differences between the two commands is that the first uses `-in cert.pem -certfile chain.pem` and the second one simply `-in fullchain.pem`. I presume the difference lies somewhere in there, but I wouldn't know exactly what.